# AMO get partitions where data are processed but not indexes

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssas, olap

I am writing a script that return all unprocessed partitions within a measure group using the following command:

```
objMeasureGroup.Partitions.Cast<Partition>().Where(x => x.State != AnalysisState.Processed)
```

After doing some experiments, it looks like this property indicates if the data is processed and doesn't mention the indexes.

After searching for hours, i didn't find any method to list the partitions where data is processed but indexes are not.

Any suggestions?

---

*Environment:*

- SQL Server 2014
- SSAS multidimensional cube
- Script are written within a SSIS package / Script task

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, ProcessIndexes is an incremental operation. So if you run it twice the second time will be pretty quick because there is nothing to do. So I would recommend just running it on the cube and not worrying about whether it was previously run. However if you do need to analyze the current state then read on.

The best way (only way I know of) to distinguish whether ProcessIndexes has been run on a partition is to study the `DISCOVER_PARTITION_STAT` and `DISCOVER_PARTITION_DIMENSION_STAT` DMVs as seen below.

The `DISCOVER_PARTITION_STAT` DMV returns one row per aggregation with the rowcount. The first row of that DMV has a blank aggregation name and represents the rowcount of the lowest level data processed in that partition.

The `DISCOVER_PARTITION_DIMENSION_STAT` DMV can tell you about whether indexes are processed and which range of values by each dimension attribute are in this partition (by internal IDs, so not super easy to interpret). We assume at least one dimension attribute is set to be optimized so it will be indexed.

You will need to add a reference to Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient also to simplify running these DMVs:

```
string sDatabaseName = "YourDatabaseName";
string sCubeName = "YourCubeName";
string sMeasureGroupName = "YourMeasureGroupName";
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server s = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server();
s.Connect("Data Source=localhost");
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database db = s.Databases.GetByName(sDatabaseName);
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Cube c = db.Cubes.GetByName(sCubeName);
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.MeasureGroup mg = c.MeasureGroups.GetByName(sMeasureGroupName);

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection conn = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection(s.ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

foreach (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Partition p in mg.Partitions)
{
    Console.Write(p.Name + " - " + p.State + " - ");
    var restrictions = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdRestrictionCollection();
    restrictions.Add("DATABASE_NAME", db.Name);
    restrictions.Add("CUBE_NAME", c.Name);
    restrictions.Add("MEASURE_GROUP_NAME", mg.Name);
    restrictions.Add("PARTITION_NAME", p.Name);
    var dsAggs = conn.GetSchemaDataSet("DISCOVER_PARTITION_STAT", restrictions);
    var dsIndexes = conn.GetSchemaDataSet("DISCOVER_PARTITION_DIMENSION_STAT", restrictions);
    if (dsAggs.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("ProcessData not run yet");
    else if (dsAggs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 1)
        Console.WriteLine("aggs processed");
    else if (p.AggregationDesign == null || p.AggregationDesign.Aggregations.Count == 0)
    {
        bool bIndexesBuilt = false;
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dsIndexes.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["ATTRIBUTE_INDEXED"]))
            {
                bIndexesBuilt = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (bIndexesBuilt)
            Console.WriteLine("indexes have been processed. no aggs defined");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("no aggs defined. need to run ProcessIndexes on this partition to build indexes");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("need to run ProcessIndexes on this partition to process aggs and indexes");
}
```

Comment: Very useful information. But it is weird why there is no IsIndexesProcessed property for Cube objects.

Comment: I have posted a separate answer to add more information, check it out

Answer (score 4):

*I am posting this answer as additional information of @GregGalloway excellent answer*

After searching for a while, the only way to know if partition are processed is using `DISCOVER_PARTITION_STAT` and `DISCOVER_PARTITION_DIMENSION_STAT`.

I found an article posted by Daren Gossbel describing the whole process:

- [SSAS: Are my Aggregations processed?](http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2008/12/02/ssas-are-my-aggregations-processed.aspx)

In the artcile above the author provided two methods:

1. using XMLA

> One way in which you can find it out with an XMLA discover call to the DISCOVER_PARTITION_STAT rowset, but that returns the results in big lump of XML which is not as easy to read as a tabular result set.

*example*

```xml
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">

    <RequestType>DISCOVER_PARTITION_STAT</RequestType>

    <Restrictions>
        <RestrictionList>
      <DATABASE_NAME>Adventure Works DW</DATABASE_NAME>
      <CUBE_NAME>Adventure Works</CUBE_NAME>
      <MEASURE_GROUP_NAME>Internet Sales</MEASURE_GROUP_NAME>
      <PARTITION_NAME>Internet_Sales_2003</PARTITION_NAME>
    </RestrictionList>
    </Restrictions>

    <Properties>
        <PropertyList>
           </PropertyList>
    </Properties>

</Discover>
```

2. using DMV queries

> If you have SSAS 2008, you can use the new DMV feature to query this same rowset and return a tabular result.

*example*

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SystemRestrictSchema($system.discover_partition_stat
        ,DATABASE_NAME = 'Adventure Works DW 2008'
        ,CUBE_NAME = 'Adventure Works'
        ,MEASURE_GROUP_NAME = 'Internet Sales'
        ,PARTITION_NAME = 'Internet_Sales_2003')
```

---

**Similar posts:**

- [How to find out using AMO if aggregation exists on partition?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b479e8ba-b5a9-4475-9f0c-1fc703e16246/how-to-find-out-using-amo-if-aggregation-exists-on-partition?forum=sqlanalysisservices)
- [Detect aggregation processing state with AMO?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b86b189e-f2ee-484f-ac91-2618ffb9b4be/detect-aggregation-processing-state-with-amo?forum=sqlanalysisservices)